# Can I clear a persistent variable in workspace A from workspace B?

Tags: matlab

I have a script with a GUI that loads in a block of data and then performs a nonlinear fit to each row of the data using `lsqnonlin`. The model function requires some ancillary calculations (weight functions, table lookups, etc.) that don't change between iterations, so I calculate them at the very beginning and then store them in persistent variables. So far so good.

However, Once I return control to my GUI and want to fit the next set of data, those persistent variables are still there, and may not be appropriate for the next dataset. I tried passing a flag to my fitting function to let it know whether to clear. My current code looks something like this (greatly simplified):

```
constants.firstRun = true;
constants.otherStuff = [other stuff I need for fit];
for k = 1:K
    data = load(dataFile(k))
    [N,M] = size(data);
    if k == 1
        normalizedIndex = linspace(0,1,N);
    end
    for m = 1:M
        dataToFit = data(:,m)
        constants.dataToFit = dataToFit;
        if k == 1 && m == 1
            Ao = estimateStartingParameters(normalizedIndex,dataToFit);
        else
            Ao = A;
        end
        nlFitFun = @(ao) modelFunction(ao,normalizedIndex,constants);
        A = lsqnonlin(nlFitFun,Ao);
        % do things with A like calculate, plot, save etc.
        constants.firstRun = false;
    end
end
```

and then the model function looks like

```
function Y = modelFunction(ao,normalizedIndex,constants)
persistent Z

if constants.firstRun
    Z = longCalculation(constants.otherStuff);
end

X = calculation(ao,Z,normalizedIndex);
Y = fullModel(ao,X,constants) - constants.dataToFit;
```

The problem here is that for the first fit, `constants.firstRun` is always true, so it *always* calculates `Z`, before being set.

The question is, is there a way to reach into the function to clear the persistent variables from the main script? The other option I thought of was to just add the persistent variables to the `constants` structure variable, but `Z` is large (and this is simplified, there are actually multiple persistent variables). Are there memory or other overhead issues when passing a large variable into and out of a function? For that matter, do I actually gain anything by using persistent variables rather than passing the variables into the function each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`clear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html).  If you pass it the name of a function, it will reinitialize all persistent variables within the function.

Comment: This is what the OP needs.  You just beat me to it.  :)

Comment: That worked! In my defense, I've got 2013a and the help file for `clear` says nothing about this. The line "If name is a function name, then clear name reinitializes any persistent variables in the function." is new to the 2013b help file.